# ODBC SQL IIF With Group By - Aggregate Function Error

Tags: sql, group-by, iif

Here is the ODBC SQL statement I want to run. ODBC is the connection type and the query is run against an Excel spreadsheet's named range. The best I can tell SQL is used and all prior queries have worked as expected.

```
select
IIF([Account Name]='Account1','Special Account','Not Special') as AccountType,
IIF([Recipe]='Recipe1','American','Other') as FoodType,
sum([Unpaid])
from MyData
Group by [Account Name]
```

Here is the error message I get.

"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function."

I know this means I have to add [Recipe] to the Group by so the Group by will look like this.

```
Group by [Account Name],[Recipe]
```

If I make this change the SQL statement does run, but I can't have the output Group by both fields. This returns results that I do not and cannot work with. I really only want to Group by [Account Name].

How do I do this? The IIF statements are needed in this query to return the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not in an aggregate function it needs to be in a group by. SUM() is the only aggregate function you have - the others go in the group by.

```
select
IIF([Account Name]='Account1','Special Account','Not Special') as AccountType,
IIF([Recipe]='Recipe1','American','Other') as FoodType,
sum([Unpaid])
from MyData
Group by IIF([Account Name]='Account1','Special Account','Not Special'),
IIF([Recipe]='Recipe1','American','Other')
```

Comment: I know that I have to add to the Group by, but this does not solve my problem as adding to the group by nets results I can not use. I mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @user2027231  Your question has you grouping by the column names, I'm grouping by the IIF statements. Maybe update your question with the output you are expecting?